# Arduino Mega 2560 serial port location

Tags: arduino-mega

I am having trouble finding the serial input (or port whatever) on my mega can someone plz show me a pic of this pin thanks

Comment: Please read our [ask] page and then edit your question.

Comment: what is a `port whatever` ?

Comment: your posting shows no effort to find the answer on your own.

Answer (score 2):

For information on an Arduino board your first stop should always be the product page, which contains some helpful documentation. For the Mega 2560 the page is https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-mega-2560-rev3. If you had checked there you would see this:

> Serial: 0 (RX) and 1 (TX); Serial 1: 19 (RX) and 18 (TX); Serial 2: 17 (RX) and 16 (TX); Serial 3: 15 (RX) and 14 (TX). Used to receive (RX) and transmit (TX) TTL serial data. Pins 0 and 1 are also connected to the corresponding pins of the ATmega16U2 USB-to-TTL Serial chip.

You will find those pins on the rightmost header on the top edge of the board in this picture:
[image: Mega 2560 serial pins]